# Android request response is too long

Tags: android, json, request

I am polling my webservice and receiving a response which is very long (its supposed to be a json)

but because it's too long, the system truncates the end of it

and i receive a json that looks like this `{"object":["one","two", ....`
which is of course not a valid json anymore.
3 dots instead of the correct json ending.
There is nothing i can do about the length of the json.
Is there anything i can do to receive all of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused between what you can print in debug, and this can be truncated by Android logs, and what you exactly receive from the server. Either try to print out what you get as a response in a file (on sdcard) or just print out the length of the received stuff.

But there are no chances that a response is truncated in http, think about downloading a huge file of several Mb, except if there is really something very wrong on the server side, like a bad content-length.

Comment: Agree that he doubt for log cat output. No output is truncated from server until and unless it is coded. It may possible that response time is long. But if you set time out, you will definitely get huge response also. :)

Comment: Indeed i did get the full response, the problem seemed to be the function that i used to convert the input stream to string. I needed to provide the correct charset for it, as it converted some hebrew characters to gibbrish which made my gson go nutz ;) which is why i thought i may have not received the entire response